# standalone compatibility with pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages, standalone

I've done the following:

```
\documentclass[preview]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\includepdf[pages=1] {example-image-a4-numbered}
More testing
\end{document}
```

and I get a 3-page document: "This is a test" on the first page, a picture from my pdf on the second page, and "More testing" on the third page.

When I change to this:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\includepdf[pages=1] {example-image-a4-numbered}
More testing
\end{document}
```

I get something that looks like this:
[image]

...and the PDF contents don't show up at all. Can someone suggest what's up? (I've tried about 5 different PDFs just to be sure I'm not fighting something weird about one particular PDF.)

I'm on a Mac, using TeXShop.

Comment: You can use \includegraphics[page=1]{...}.  That's what pdfpages does.

Comment: OK...that seems to have worked. But is there a reason that pdfpages did NOT work?

Comment: There are lots of reasons.  For example, \paperwidth and \paperheight are undefined.

Comment: Sigh. Of course there's no hint of an error message...and I once again remember my love/hate relationship with LaTeX.

Comment: `standalone` is designed for diagrams and other boxed content and changes the internal page definitions for that. When other package are used which do similar things then clashes can occur easily. You could just try to use the `preview` package with `article` class instead.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` are actually defined, but will change before the page is shipped out.